# MYSQL: count rows with same date

Tags: mysql, database

I got a table called `event_details` summarized as below:

```
Id creation_date
 1 2015-03-18 18:59
 2 2015-03-18 17:59
 3 2015-03-18 16:59
 4 2015-03-17 14:59
 5 2015-03-17 18:59
 6 2015-03-17 19:59
 7 2015-03-16 11:59
 8 2015-03-15 03:59
 9 2015-03-15 02:59
10 2015-03-15 08:59
11 2015-03-14 09:59
```

I want to count rows with the same date and get result like below?

How can I do this? Is it possible using nested queries or I should use joins?

```
cnt creation_date
  3 2015-03-18
  3 2015-03-17
  1 2015-03-16
  3 2015-03-15
  1 2015-03-14
```

And a final question: Is this naturally a heavy SQL task and impose high loads to database-server or not?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), creation_date FROM table_name GROUP BY creation_date
```

This first groups all your rows with the same creation_date and then counts the number of rows in each group. You can furthermore order the rows as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), creation_date FROM table_name GROUP BY creation_date ORDER BY creation_date
```

Comment: I don't know why I confused and could not imagine this!

Comment: above creation date also has time, so it should also exclude time and then group by the only date not time then show the results

Answer (score 8):

This could be done with `group by` and `count`

```
select 
count(*) as cnt,
date(creation_date) as creation_date_date
from event_details
group by creation_date_date
```

Comment: how can i remove the time part? since records are date/time.

Comment: `date(creation_date) as creation_date_date` does it for you.

Answer (score 5):

This does it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt,
       date(creation_date) as creation_date 
FROM event_details 
GROUP BY 2
```